# Xamarin Event when page visible

Tags: forms, xamarin

Need to have an event to be fired every time a page on my app is visible again (got focus).
Example: My app opens a browser, or people opens another app.
I need an event when browser or other app is closed and my app page becomes VISIBLE (on top) again.
OnAppearing() does not works in this case.
Is there a way to fire this event ?

Regards

Comment: the App class has an OnResume method that is called when the app resumes from the background

Comment: tks Jason, it worked fine